# Animate el with translate3d and jquery

Tags: jquery, css, css-transforms

i'm trying to achieve this effect:

http://www.kennedyandoswald.com/

The one where you move the cursor and all the elements in the page move including the background with some kind of easing effect too.

What i have so far:

```
$(document).on('mousemove', '#slide1', function (e) {
        var pageX = e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 2);
        var pageY = e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 2);
        var newvalueX = width * pageX * -1 - 25;
        var newvalueY = height * pageY * -1 - 50;


        $('.el').css({
            '-webkit-transform-origin': '0px 0px',
            '-webkit-transform': 'translate3d( '+newvalueX+'px, '+newvalueY+'px, 0px) scale(1, 1) rotate(0deg)'
        });    

    });
```

So i'm moving the mouse and the .el is animating, almost as similar as the website, but the movement still isn't fluid and long enough..

The css in the .el in order to add the easing is:

```
.el{
    float: right;
    margin: 4% 8% 0 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
```

Can someone help me or point me the way to achieve that same effect?

Comment: A live example with what you have so far would aid us in aiding you

Comment: its a bit complex to make a fiddle out of it.. but what i'm trying to achieve is the exact same as in the link i posted. If you could explain me how they reached that result i think it would be enough for me.